# Joomla 3 tags hide name and date

Tags: joomla3.2

I need to hide author and date in Tagged Items view and I can't find the code to remove.

http://dev30.ncld.org/stage-related-content-my-child-is-struggling-with-learning

Thanks,
Janet

Comment: Have you tried the global article settings in `Content>Article Manager>Options` ?

Comment: Yes, Article manager settings do not affect tags. I need authors to show in articles.

Comment: Have you any template overrides for the tags view?

Comment: That was what I was going to do, but I cannot find the code in the file to change. I am using Tagged Items view in the menu.

Comment: The code in this view is generated inside the `site>components>com_tag>views>tag>default_item.php` inside the `ul` however I can't reproduce your situation and the code on your page seems to be already an override. Try fiddling around with it and tell me. Also, do you have any third party plugins enabled that might affect the view in some way?

Comment: I don't have any plugins affecting this content...could you tell me which line of code in that file. I downloaded a fresh copy to take a look and I still don't see where author and date are being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that your template (yoo_nano) renders the content on its own way. As they say about their custom renderers:

`To get an impression of how the element renderer work, go to /components/com_zoo/renderer/. Within this folder there are several files that contain the standard element renderers.`

I don't have experience with yoo themes but you can check their documentation [here](http://www.yootheme.com/support/documentation) especially the warp 6 docs [here](http://www.yootheme.com/themes/documentation?view=docs) and this about the custom renderers [here](http://www.yootheme.com/zoo/documentation/developers/create-a-new-element-renderer) located in `/media/zoo/applications/APPLICATION/templates/TEMPLATE/renderer/`. I also think that you could ask them since I think it's a commercial template.

Comment: I'm not using Zoo, but your comment made me realize that the template had a built in html override for tags. When I disabled that, I got the output I wanted! Thanks for steering me in the right direction!

Comment: Glad I helped! Consider closing the question.